How to centralize choice lists in a single file
Hy,
here is my code in a 'vue' file :
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const itemsFruits = ref([
  { text: 'APPLE', value: 'apple' },
  { text: 'LEMON', value: 'lemon' },
])

const itemsVegetables = ref([
  { text: 'POTATO', value: 'potato' },
  { text: 'ONION', value: 'onion' },
])

</script>
<template>
  <main>
      <label for="fruitsField">my favorite fruit :</label>
      <select 
        class="fruits-select" name="fruits" id="fruitsField"
        autofocus tabindex="10">
        <option disabled value="">Choose</option>
        <option v-for="(itemsFruits, index) in items" v-bind:value="itemsFruits.value">{{ itemsFruits.text }}</option>
      </select>

      <label for="vegetablesField">my favorite vegetable :</label>
      <select 
        class="vegetables-select" name="vegetables" id="vegetablesField"
        autofocus tabindex="11">
        <option disabled value="">Choose</option>
        <option v-for="(itemsVegetables, index) in items" v-bind:value="itemsVegetables.value">{{ itemsVegetables.text }}</option>
      </select>  
  </main>

enter image description here
I want to isolate const  in a separate file (js or vue)
How to do ?
I tested an instruction export instruction

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
